# Where is my cronlog?

Tags: cron

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where is the cron / crontab log?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56683/where-is-the-cron-crontab-log)

While trying to Google this a lot of sources claims there's a cron log in `/var/log` but I have none. I'm fairly convinced cron has run and I know it is running because of:

```
service cron status
cron start/running, process 19574
```

Is there some setting I need to set?

Comment: This is answered here:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/966194/16-04-how-do-i-make-cron-create-cron-log-and-monitor-it-in-real-time?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in ubuntu CRON events are sent to the syslog

i.e.

```
sudo grep CRON /var/log/syslog
```