# Where is the cron / crontab log?

Tags: cron, log

I want to verify that my cron job is executing and at what time.  I believe there is a log for my `sudo crontab -e` jobs, but where?

I searched google and found recommendations to look in `/var/log` (in which I do not see anything with 'cron' in the name) and to edit the file `/etc/syslog.conf` which I also do not have.

Comment: Beware that in the `crontab` context the `%` character creates a new line, so a misuse of it (i.e. not escaping it, e.g. in `date +"%Y-%m-%d"`) may prevent correct logging (`date +%Y-%m-%d >> /tmp/cron.log` won’t work).  Also, [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/449651/why-is-my-crontab-not-working-and-how-can-i-troubleshoot-it) may help.

Comment: I couldn't figure out why my cron jobs weren't running until I saw Skippy's comment. I was using the syntax `script.sh >> "build-logs-$(date +%Y%m).txt"` to save logs. Escaping the `%` fixed it i.e. `script.sh >> "build-logs-$(date +\%Y\%m).txt"`

Answer (score 1405):

On a default installation cron jobs will be logged to

```
/var/log/syslog
```

You can see just cron jobs in that logfile by running

```
grep CRON /var/log/syslog
```

If you haven't reconfigured anything, the entries will be in there.

Comment: If there is no MTA installed, cron just throws the job output away.

Comment: The cron log may be in another file in the `/var/log/` directory. Check for cron.log or equivalent.

Comment: use journalctl | grep cron on systemd systems

Comment: this doesn't give me output from the job. it just gives a generic message that the cron was processed.

Comment: I have no MTA installed, but the output is saved to `/var/log/syslog`. It rotates daily.

Comment: ...and if the syslog gets cycled you might find your information in either /var/log/syslog.1 or in one of the compressed /var/log/syslog.*.gz files.

Comment: I needed to use lowercase `cron` in the grep because the error message I was looking for was: `Jan 18 10:40:01 hostname cron[1079]: (*system*filename) INSECURE MODE (group/other writable) (/etc/cron.d/filename)`

Comment: on AWS it was /var/log/cron

Comment: What if you're not root, so you can't access syslog, so is there a log for the user-specific crontab?

Comment: I have two line(job) on crontab, but your command just shows one of them!

Comment: @shadi you could also `grep -i CRON` to search case-insensitive

Comment: On Systemd systems (better than Student's suggestion): `journalctl -u cronie`. Replace cronie with whatever cron implementation you are using. Add an e before the u to skip to the end automatically, or an f to show new entries as they appear.

Comment: File not exists for me in Ubuntu 18.04 container

Comment: If mail hasn't been configured, any messages emitted by user crontabs will stay in mailbox file `/var/mail/$USER`.

Comment: If you want pretty colours, run: `grc grep CRON /var/log/syslog`

Comment: ` grep log /var/log/syslog` is cool

Answer (score 376):

You can create a cron.log file to contain just the CRON entries that show up in syslog. Note that CRON jobs will still show up in syslog if you follow the following directions.

Open the file

```
/etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf
```

Find the line that starts with:

```
#cron.*
```

uncomment that line, save the file, and restart rsyslog:

```
sudo service rsyslog restart
```

You should now see a cron log file here:

```
/var/log/cron.log
```

Cron activity will now be logged to this file (in addition to syslog).

Note that in cron.log you will see entries for when cron ran scripts in /etc/cron.hourly, cron.daily, etc. - e.g. something like:

```
Apr 12 14:17:01 cd CRON[14368]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
```

However, you will not see more information about what scripts were actually ran inside /etc/cron.daily or /etc/cron.hourly, unless those scripts direct output to the cron.log (or perhaps to some other log file).

If you want to verify if a crontab is running and not have to search for it in cron.log or syslog, create a crontab that redirects output to a log file of your choice - something like:

```
01 14 * * * /home/joe/myscript >> /home/log/myscript.log 2>&1
```

This will redirect all standard output and errors that may be produced by the script that is run to the log file specified.

Comment: With my opinion, this answer is better in future. So your syslog file is more clear.

Comment: To also exclude the cron log from syslog you can change the line `*.*;auth,authpriv.none                -/var/log/syslog` to `*.*;auth,authpriv.none,cron.none                -/var/log/syslog`.

Comment: On our CentOS 6, cron.* defined in /etc/rsyslog.conf, whereas i's empty in rsyslog.d folder.

Comment: what is `2>&1` stand for ?

Comment: @JohnJoe 2>&1 is used to forward stderr to stdout, this way you'll also get stderr to log file.

Comment: How do you configure the amount of days of log to retain? This is my issue with syslog - I only see what happened today.

Comment: @SridharSarnobat on Ubuntu and Debian see `/etc/logrotate.d/rsyslog` - there you will see at the top that `/var/log/syslog` is rotated daily and keeps 7 days worth of logs. Scroll down and you should see that `/var/log/cron.log` will be rotated weekly and keeps an additional 4 weeks of logs. You can [override the logrotate configuration](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/382909/how-can-i-properly-override-logrotate-policies) if you need something else.

Comment: literally spent hours figuring out why i had no cronlogs, this solved it. thanks!

Answer (score 129):

Sometimes it can be useful to continuously monitor it, in that case:

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog | grep CRON
```

Comment: Well, you probably want to use `-F`, which will follow the file across name changes, so that when it gets truncated/moved to, e.g. `/var/log/syslog.1.gz`, you're still following the current `/var/log/syslog` file. Per the man docs, this is the same as running `tail xxxx -f --retry`

Answer (score 85):

You can also direct the output of the individual cronjobs to their own logs for better readability, you will just need to append the output of date somewhere.

```
 0 15 * * *    /home/andrew/daily-backup.sh >> /var/log/daily-backup.log 2>&1
```

Comment: true, but if this line fails to run due to syntax error, nothing will be written in the output log specified.

Comment: You can solve this by appending 2>&1 after the log file is specified.  It is also best practice to test your cronjobs before adding them to the crontab, and then being present for the first scheduled run to ensure that the crontab is properly formatted.

Comment: If `daily-backup.log` file doesn't exist, CRON creates it automatically.

Comment: This is really helpful as my PHP results are appended to the log. The only negative is there are no line breaks.

Answer (score 53):

If you have `systemd` installed on your system, you could display cron job log by using the `journalctl` command.

For example, on my Ubuntu 17.10:

```
journalctl -u cron.service
```

Comment: If you use cronie, try `journalctl -u cronie.service`

Answer (score 32):

```
journalctl -t CROND
```

on ubuntu >=18 it maybe

```
journalctl -t CRON
```

From the `journalctl` manual:

```
   -t, --identifier=SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER|PATTERN
       Show messages for the specified syslog identifier SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER, 
       or for any of the messages with a "SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER" matched by PATTERN.

       This parameter can be specified multiple times.
```

Comment: On an ubuntu 20, you can use the tag CRON, the tag CROND does not give any results.

Comment: On RHEL 7, most jobs are run by `anacron` and `/var/log/cron` has much more useful info than `journalctl -t CROND`

Answer (score 17):

This is a very old question, but none of these answers seem satisfactory.

First make your cron job run every minute, then run cron as non-daemon (temporarily, just kill any crond that may have already started) with test logging:

`crond -nx test`

And see the log of your program execution flowing through your terminal.

Comment: Does not run on 14.04 - `No command 'crond' found, did you mean:
 Command 'cron' from package 'cron' (main)`

Comment: Same error on Ubuntu 18.04 today

Comment: crond and cron is the same, crond is used in RedHat, CentOS and Suse platforms. And cron is used in Ubuntu. So dependes on your system, use crond or cron.

Answer (score 14):

You could redirect the output of `cron` to a temporary file.
Such as:

```
00 11 07 * * /bin/bash /home/ubuntu/command.sh > /tmp/output 2>&1
```

Error and normal output, both will be redirected to the same file

Answer (score 13):

It is in `/var/log/syslog` by default.

But it can be set up to create a separate cron.log, which is more useful.

This Q&A describes the process:

[16.04: How do I make cron create cron.log and monitor it in real time?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966194/16-04-how-do-i-make-cron-create-cron-log-and-monitor-it-in-real-time/966195#966195)

Also in this answer is the instructions to create a `wcron` command that displays it is near-real-time.  Plus, it links to another answer,

[How to change cron log level?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/949996/how-to-change-cron-log-level/)

that shows how to change the log level to include more than just the start of jobs - level 15 will show errors and end time, also.

Answer (score 12):

Like mentioned earlier, cron jobs get logged to `/var/log/syslog`

You can pipe the syslog to grep and filter out the CRON logs, like this

```
less /var/log/syslog | grep CRON
```

You can search through your crontab logs, like this

```
less /var/log/syslog | grep CRON | grep <search-keyword-comes-here>
```

You can search through your crontab history logs stored in gz files, like this

```
less /var/log/syslog.2.gz | grep CRON | grep <search-keyword-comes-here>
```

Its always considered good to have a logging mechanism, you can quickly setup [ELK](https://www.elastic.co/elk-stack) for your servers, you can also experiment with [logz](https://logz.io/) .

Answer (score 7):

this shows CRON runtime i used Centos 7

```
cat /var/log/cron
```

Comment: CentOS != Ubuntu ...

Answer (score 5):

On Ubuntu 20.04, `/var/mail/{user}` had the cron messages i was looking for.

I couldn't find decent cron logs in `/var/log/messages`.

Comment: Wasn't a question, I'm posting an answer because I found cron logs in /var/mail/{user} instead of /var/log/messages or /var/log/cron or /var/log/syslog described in other answers.

Comment: The actual output of the command is sent in the mail. Information in /var/log/syslog which just reports that cron was run. Good answer!

Answer (score 4):

Check all CRON related logs in syslog files included compressed log files as well like this way:

```
zless /var/log/syslog* | grep CRON
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the current cron logs in `/var/log/cron`
and previous logs on `/var/log/cron-date`.

Answer (score 1):

It may be different depending on the system type and edition. But in many cases, you have to figure out the time basis that the target crontab rule runs on. So for example, if you're searching for the related log for a daily crontab rule, then you'll find the log divided into different files, one per day, in:

```
$ ls -ltrh /var/log/cron-*
```

And you'll get the logfiles.

Answer (score 0):

It is strange but my cron is reporting into mail:

```
You have new mail in /var/mail/xerostomus
$ mail 
Mail version 8.1.2 01/15/2001.  Type ? for help.
"/var/mail/xerostomus": 6 messages 6 new
>N  1 root@localhost.lo  Wed Sep 13 15:59   24/852   Cron <xerostomus@T430> env DISPLAY=:0 /home/xerostomus/idesk_cron.sh
```

By the way I am experimenting with Debian... :-)

If I need to log something in cron I use this simple task:

```
echo "cron report: variableA($variableA)" >> /dev/shm/grep.tmp
```

Not very smart, but works... :-)