# How to see full cron log (Not of just 1 day or less)?

Tags: 16.04, cron, log, automation

I want see all the jobs that has been scheduled by using cron for the last 1 week (or certain specified time). I used the command

```
sudo grep CRON /var/log/syslog
```

But it only shows the log for 1 day. Is there any command in Ubuntu to track them?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/56683/where-is-the-cron-crontab-log#121560

Comment: @pa4080 That answer only shows the log for a day or even less. I needed more and have got the answer too. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this to newer syslog files:

```
cd /var/log
cat syslog.1 syslog | grep CRON
```

To the oldest you must do it:

```
cd /var/log
zcat syslog syslog.4.gz syslog.3.gz syslog.2.gz | grep CRON
```

It's a good idea to do these commands nested in loops, specially to zcat, since syslog.#.gz are more numerous.

You can even store them into another file to analyze better:

```
cd /var/log
zcat syslog syslog.4.gz syslog.3.gz syslog.2.gz | grep CRON > ~/cronanalysis.txt
cat syslog.1 syslog | grep CRON >> ~/cronanalysis.txt
```

The order of syslog files is inverted, so you put older to head and newer events to tail.

Answer (score 8):

Another alternative is

```
sudo zgrep CRON /var/log/syslog*
```

`zgrep` uncompresses files if needed. Options same as for `grep`.

Answer (score 0):

On Amazon Linux you can find it in
`/var/log/cron` file

```
tail /var/log/cron
```