# Git Pull and then Push via Cron in Ubuntu

Tags: bash, scripts, cron, git

I am in a git enterprise environment and there is a git repo where I pull the whole code, build it using [gulp.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gulp.js) and then copy the distribution to another repo, where I push it to remote.

I have automated all that in a bash script and whenever I execute `sh gittogulp.sh` it does that flawlessly. But when I use a cronjob to do that, it fails to pull new content from git and makes gulp.js builds from content that is already there.

I want to know, how can I pull from a git repo without manually triggering the script. Webhooks is not an option for me.

`gittogulp.sh` is:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ~/mainrepo
git checkout dev
git fetch
echo "Pulling latest code from git repo"
git pull

for commitid in $(git log --format="%h" -n 10)
do
    git checkout dev
    echo "git reset hard"
    git fetch --all
    git reset --hard origin/dev
    echo "Checkout commit id: ""$commitid"
    echo git checkout "$commitid"
    git checkout "$commitid"
    echo "Installing dependencies"
    npm install
    echo "Gulpifying the code"
    gulp dev
    basefolder="/root/mainrepo/manifests"
    basedestfolder="/root/outputrepo/dev"
    if [ -d "$basefolder" ]; then

        versionrepo=`cat "$basefolder"/version.txt`
        echo "Version in repo: ""$versionrepo"
        destfolder="$basedestfolder""/""$commitid"

        if [ -d "$destfolder" ]; then
            echo "Latest outputs are already in place"
            break
        else
            echo "copying latest output to ""$destfolder"
            mkdir "$destfolder"
            cp -r "$basefolder" "$destfolder"
            zipname="$versionrepo""_""$commitid"".zip"
            zipdestpath="$basedestfolder""/""$zipname"
            echo "Making new zip from latest commit"
            echo zip -r "$zipdestpath" "$destfolder"
            zip -r "$zipdestpath" "$destfolder"
        fi

    else
        echo "$basefolder"" : folder doesn't exist, exiting"
    fi
done

cd ~/outputrepo
git pull
git add .
git commit -m "adding new zip"
git push
```

Comment: What exactly is in the script? Have you kept the error output when run via cron, like in https://askubuntu.com/a/604036/158442? If not, do so and add the output to the question.

Comment: I have added the script now. No, i have not added the logs, i didn't know that. i'll do it now and paste it here.