# Command not working in crontab, but work in terminal

Tags: cron

I have command in crontab:

```
20 * * * *      root    /usr/bin/find /home/user/temps/ -type f -mmin +20 -delete
```

If I run this command in terminal everything works fine, but in /etc/crontab doesn't work. What am I doing wrong? Ubuntu 18.04
in journalctl -u cron.service

```
CRON[17590]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
CRON[17591]: (root) CMD (/usr/bin/find /home/user/temps/ -type f -mmin +15 -delete )
CRON[17590]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
```

if i add > /tmp/output to command - file empty

Comment: verify if command in crontab is executing or check crontab logs referring to  https://askubuntu.com/q/56683/283843

Comment: What crontab are you using ? Did you edit /etc/crontab file with the above line or did you add it to your own / root's crontab with `crontab -e` ?

Comment: I use /etc/crontab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strange problem, but i fix it just restart my server. After reboot cron start working.